# How to extend this file app/code/Magedelight/SMSNotification/Helper/Data.php in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, helper, file, function

I want to extend app/code/Magedelight/SMSNotification/Helper/Data.php this file in my custom module.

I have created a module.

My di.xml file app/code/Hl/Smsnotification/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magedelight\SMSNotification\Helper\Data" type="Hl\Smsnotification\Helper\Smsdata" />
</config>
```

My Helper File app/code/Hl/Smsnotification/Helper/Smsdata.php

```
<?php

namespace Hl\Smsnotification\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

use Magedelight\SMSNotification\Helper\Data as MainHelper;

class Smsdata extends MainHelper
{    
private $storeManager;
private $localecurrency;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->localecurrency = $localeCurrency;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**  @return array */
public function getOrderData($order)
{
    $_order = $order->getOrder($order);
    if ($order->getGrandTotal()) {
        $total =$order->getGrandTotal();
    } else {
        $total = $order->getPayment()->getAmountOrdered();
    }
    
    $currency_code = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
    $currency_symbol = $this->localecurrency->getCurrency($currency_code)
                            ->getSymbol();

    $orderData          =   [
        'firstname'     =>  $order->getCustomerFirstname(),
        'lastname'      =>  $order->getCustomerLastname(),
        'order_id'      =>  ($_order) ? $_order->getIncrementId() : $order->getIncrementId(),
        'total'         =>  $currency_symbol.round($total, 2),
        'orderitem'     =>  $this->getOrderedItems($order->getAllItems()),
        'orderitemsizes'     =>  $this->getOrderedItemsdata($order->getAllVisibleItems()),
        'store'         => $this->getCurrentStoreName()
    ];
    return $orderData;
}

/**  @return array */
public function getOrderedData($order)
{
    $_order = $order->getOrder($order);
    if ($order->getGrandTotal()) {
        $total =$order->getGrandTotal();
    } else {
        $total = $order->getPayment()->getAmountOrdered();
    }
    
    $currency_code = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
    $currency_symbol = $this->localecurrency->getCurrency($currency_code)
                            ->getSymbol();

    $orderData          =   [
        'firstname'     =>  $order->getCustomerFirstname(),
        'lastname'      =>  $order->getCustomerLastname(),
        'order_id'      =>  ($_order) ? $_order->getIncrementId() : $order->getIncrementId(),
        'total'         =>  $currency_symbol.round($total, 2),
        'orderitem'     =>  $this->getOrderedItems($order->getAllVisibleItems()),
        'orderitemsizes'     =>  $this->getOrderedItemsdata($order->getAllVisibleItems()),
        'store'         => $this->getCurrentStoreName()
    ];
    return $orderData;
}

public function getOrderedItemsdata($items)
{
    $order_items_sizes = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if($item->getProductOptions()){
            $order_items_sizes[] = $item->getProductOptions()['attributes_info'][1]['value'];
        }else{
            $order_items_sizes[] = '';
        }
    }

    return implode(",", $order_items_sizes);
}

public function setOrderMesageText($message, $data)
{
    $keywords   = [
        '{firstname}',
        '{lastname}',
        '{order_id}',
        '{total}',
        '{orderitem}',
        '{store}',
        '{orderitemsizes}'
    ];
    $message = str_replace($keywords, $data, $message);
    return $message;
}
}
?>
```

The product is added to cart but on checkout page it gives me an error

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Hl\Smsnotification\Helper\Smsdata, Argument 2 passed to Hl\Smsnotification\Helper\Smsdata::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface, instance of Magento\Directory\Model\Currency given, called in /var/www/html/handlfashion-new/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

Can anyone point out what is the error and how to resolve that.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: can you share Magedelight\SMSNotification\Helper\Data.php file ?

Comment: @Msquare Added the file Please check.

Comment: @Prits Worked below solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this

```
<?php

namespace Hl\Smsnotification\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magedelight\SMSNotification\Helper\Data as MainHelper;

class Smsdata extends MainHelper
{
    private $storeManager;
    private $localecurrency;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$localeCurrency,$storeManager);
        $this->localecurrency = $localeCurrency;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    ..................................................
    ..................................................
    ..................................................
```

**app/code/Hl/Smsnotification/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magedelight\SMSNotification\Helper\Data" type="Hl\Smsnotification\Helper\Smsdata" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the `Smsdata.php` constructor as below and try again.

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->localecurrency = $localeCurrency;
    parent::__construct($context, $localeCurrency, $storeManager);
}
```

we should define/specify the parent constructor parameters in the child class always.